# GWT create Image using ImageResource

Tags: java, image, gwt, gwt-2.4, clientresource

My question is really simple and shot. but hope I can have a clear answer.
We can create GWT Image in many ways.

```
Image image = new Image ( (ImageResource)imageRes);

Image image = new Image ( (ImageResource)imageRes.getSafeUri() );

Image image = new Image ();
image.setUrl((ImageResource)imageRes.getSafeUri().asString() );
```

My question is:  what are the difference among these 3 ways to create a new image using ImageResouce. Which one is best or faster for first-time loading?

Thanks

Comment: Why was this question down-voted? It is a perfectly legitimate question to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should not use the last two.

An `ImageResource` technically represents a region within a "sprited" image: it has a URL to the sprite and the coordinates of the region on that image. In many browsers, and for most images, the URL will actually be a `data:` URL and the region will represent the whole image. This can be controlled on a per-image basis using `@ImageOptions(preventInlining=true)` or globally with a `set-property` on your `gwt.xml`. In other words, your code shouldn't rely on it, and should always treat an `ImageResource` as a region within a sprited image.
FYI, the cases where a sprited image is actually used *by default* are for IE6/7 which does not support `data:` URLs, and for images that are too large to fit within a `data:` URL (all browsers).

This is however exactly what you're doing in the last two cases: use only the URL of the `ImageResource`, as if it weren't (potentially) a sprited image.